# Ubuntu 20.04 Modoboa: dovecot.service failed, and Error: Connection to IMAP server failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, dovecot, apache2

## Impacted versions

- Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04
- Arch: 32 Bits
- Database: PostgreSQL

## Steps to reproduce

- Installed Modoboa through the installer. (didn't saw any errors)
- Installed SSL certificate through `certbot` and then deleted it, and then installed again for [www.mail.domain.nl](http://www.mail.domain.nl) instead of mail.domain.nl.
- Added a domain and logged in as admin of this newly created domain into Modoboa and accessed the emailbox.

## Problem

I have first time ever installed Modoboa Webmail which has dovecot to handle IMAP and POP3, I noticed that when I execute a command to see the current running services `$ systemctl list-units --type=service`. I see that the service dovecot.service failed to run in redcolor.

Created a domain and mailbox, managed to log in but whenever I access the `www.mail.domain.com/webmail` page to see my emailbox I get the error `Error: Connection to IMAP server failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused`.

When I write the command `dovecot -F` I get:

```
doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -Pn > dovecot-new.conf
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf:45: ssl_protocols has been replaced by ssl_min_protocol
doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf line 13: ssl_cert: Can't open file /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.nl/fullchain.pem: No such file or directory
```

## Expected behavior

I think it has to do with Dovecot service showing the status of 'failed' in the service list.
Please help me haha, I want to send emails and receive on my Ubuntu server using Modoboa.

I think it has to with SSL certificate which I deleted but I have it now for [www.mail.domain.nl](http://www.mail.domain.nl) instead of mail.domain.nl the reason is certbot blocked me for one week by having too many attempts.

**EDIT: I think I need to add manually the files of**

```
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.nl/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.nl/privkey.pem
```

**Since they don't exist?**

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it the problem was inside the file of Dovecot:

```
$ cd /etc/dovecot/conf.d/
$ nano 10-ssl.conf
```

and then update the directories of

```
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.nl/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.nl/privkey.pem
```

To:
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mail.domain.nl/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mail.domain.nl/privkey.pem

Since I have added www. as subdomain because of the flood :D

```
$ sudo systemctl restart dovecot
```

Maybe we need also change postfix old subdomain:

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

But it works also without postfix fixing for me :D